# Gatling 3 - RequestTimeoutException

Tags: header, timeout, response, gatling

I'm currently using Gatling 3.1.2 which is the latest version and I have ran many performance tests using gatling and there were no major issues for my testing until this week.

Error

> 00:15:59.509 [WARN ] i.g.h.e.GatlingHttpListener - Request 'Homepage'
>   failed for user 3 io.gatling.http.client.impl.RequestTimeoutException:
>   Request timeout to  after 60000 ms

I have 4 to 5 different hosts that my performance tests uses and one of the URI is creating this problem. The health check URL for that host is responding 200 but one thing I observed is the URI which is timing out has very huge response content security policy header (I'm thinking it might be due to this)

I have tried both with proxy and without proxy.
Have also used ahc httpClientCodecMaxHeaderSize in gatling.conf but this is decpricated.